# Не отрабатывается ошибка

Tags: python

````
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, reason = None):
    await member.kick()
    try:
        if member == None:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка', description = f'```Упомяните участника для того чтобы его кикнуть```', color = discord.Colour.from_rgb(94, 163, 254)))
            return
        if reason == None:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка', description = f'```Напишите причину кика```', color = discord.Colour.from_rgb(94, 163, 254)))
            return
        
        author = ctx.message.author
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Кик', description = f'```Администратор - {author}\n' + f'Кикнул {member}, по причине:\n' f'{reason}```', color = discord.Colour.from_rgb(94, 163, 254)))
        print('Команда kick была отправлена')
        return
````

В консоль не вылазит ошибка
не работает

````
        if member == None:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка', description = f'```Упомяните участника для того чтобы его кикнуть```', color = discord.Colour.from_rgb(94, 163, 254)))
            return
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Какая именно ошибка выходит?

Comment: А, ну да, сначала же нужно на `None` проверять, а `await member.kick()` делать только если `member` не `None`

Answer (score 1):

1. Ошибка не вылазит по причине, отсутствия ее образа.

````
    try:
       if member == None:
           await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка', description = f'```Упомяните участника для того чтобы его кикнуть```', color = discord.Colour.from_rgb(94, 163, 254)))
           return
       if reason == None:
           await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка', description = f'```Напишите причину кика```', color = discord.Colour.from_rgb(94, 163, 254)))
           return
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)

>>> Это выведет ошибку вашу в консоль
Отправьте пожалуйста данную ошибку в виде дополнения к вашему вопросу, или комментарию.
````

2. Вы пополняете kick участника раньше, чем происходит сама проверка

```
await member.kick()
```

Comment: снизу я написал

Comment: @NeZuSS Я написал, что нужно добавить, что бы появился ошибка